# How to position my picture at the center of the slide in my existing powerpoint slide using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

Firstly, my charts are copied as picture and when i tried to paste it, the object doesn't support this property or method error occurred  at the line **For Each oSh In PPTPres.Slides(28)**. But ultimately, i want my picture to be pasted at the center of the slide 28, and slightly smaller. Can anyone tell me where have i done wrong here and how should i rectify it?

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub ExportChartsToPowerPoint_SingleWorksheettesting()

    'Declare PowerPoint Variables
    Dim PPTApp As Object
    Dim PPTPres As Object
    Dim PPTShape As Object
    Dim mySlide As Object
    Dim myslide2 As Object

        Dim i As Long


    'Declare Excel Variables
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject

If PPTApp Is Nothing Then _
Set PPTApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

On Error GoTo 0
        PPTApp.Visible = True

    'Create new presentation in the PowerPoint application.
      Set PPTPres = PPTApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:="\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\myassignment3\mypresentationsample.pptx")

   Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
        Set ppSlide = PPTPres.Slides(28)

        Dim j As Integer
        For j = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
            If ppSlide.Shapes(j).Type = msoPicture Then
                ppSlide.Shapes(j).Delete
            End If
        Next j


With PPTPres.Slides(28)
Sheets(4).Range("A1:M34").CopyPicture
            ppSlide.Shapes.Paste
End With


    Dim oSh As Shape

        For Each oSh In PPTPres.Slides(28) '<---object doesn't support this property or method
            With oSh
                If .Type = msoLinkedPicture _
                Or .Type = msoPicture Then

                ' position it to taste
                .Left = 100
                .Top = 100

                End If
            End With
        Next    ' Shape

End Sub
```

Currently

[image]

Expected

[image]

debug.print

[image]

Comment: `For Each oSh In PPTPres.Slides(28).Shapes`

Comment: @Tim Williams i think i have tried that before too, and i got the Type mismatch error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (example code):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim PPTApp As Object
    Dim PPTPres As Object
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    Dim oSh 'As ShapeRange
    Dim pgSet

    'using already open PPT for testing....
    Set PPTApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application") 'get open ppt
    Set ppSlide = PPTApp.Presentations(1).Slides(1)    'the open presentation
    Set pgSet = PPTApp.Presentations(1).PageSetup      'for slide width/height

    Sheets(1).Range("A1:M34").CopyPicture
    Set oSh = ppSlide.Shapes.Paste() '<< get the pasted shape

    'center on slide
    With oSh
        .Left = (pgSet.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2
        .Top = (pgSet.SlideHeight - .Height) / 2
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, it works as intended. Btw can i ask  why in the process of centering the chart on the slide, we use this equation .Left = (pgSet.SlideWidth - .Width) / 2 ? Anyways, right now im trying to minimise the size of the picture so i suppose i should use something like  .Left = (pgSet.SlideWidth - .Width) / 4 ? Likewise for the top?

Comment: And also when i use F8 to check the value of pgSet.SlideWidth and .width, it doesn't show any value which i don't understand

Comment: Try `Debug.Print oSh.Width, oSh.Height, pgSet.SlideWidth,pgSet.SlideHeight`   The equation for centering the shape on the slide assumes that it's smaller than the slide: if it isn't then you'll need to adjust its size before centering it.  As for why that equation: you need to find out how much space is around the slide, and have half on each side and top/bottom.

Comment: Sorry, another thing that bothers me is that why when i set oSh2.Width = 600, the immediate window shows 509.769(as shown in my post) but for osh2.height, everything seems fine?(Like osh2.height=400, immediate window shows the same value)

Comment: Does that matter though?  I’m not sure there’s a real difference there.  Do you have the aspect ratio locked?

Comment: i didn't lock the aspect ratio. Actually is just a small issue. Im just abit concern whether when i input oSh2.Width = 600, the real output is it actually 600 or 509.769?

Comment: I don't know why it's different from what you set - something to do with coordinate systems/scree resolution or something like that.  Still - the difference should not be significant.